# ListView stops updating after few seconds when I bind a ListView to ReactiveList

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, system.reactive, reactiveui

I am developing an app with Xamarin.Forms, trying to leverage ReactiveUI, but Xamarin.Forms ListView does not behave as expected.

The test setup is an Entry field which I input values into. I subscribe to changes on the ReactiveList and add the value to a ListView.

**The problem: The ListView updates for a few seconds and then just stops. 
Console still logs inputs.**

Sample code below:

```
<!-- xaml layouts omitted for brevity -->         
      <Entry x:Name="searchbox" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             Text="{Binding SearchQuery, Mode=TwoWay}"
         />
      <ListView x:Name="ResultView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Address}"></TextCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

ViewModel + SearchResult class:

```
public class SearchViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveList<SearchResult> SearchResults { get; set; }

    private string searchQuery;
    public string SearchQuery
    {
        get { return searchQuery; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref searchQuery, value); }
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<List<SearchResult>> Search { get; set; }


    public SearchViewModel()
    {
        // Set up our ListView data list
        this.SearchResults = new ReactiveList<SearchResult>();
        this.SearchResults.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

        Search = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(async _ => {
            return await GenerateSearchResultAsync(this.SearchQuery);
        });

        Search.Subscribe(results => {
            SearchResults.Clear(); // just replace output every time
            SearchResults.AddRange(results);

            // output results to console
            results.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r.Address));
        });

        // this used to contain a condition I removed for brevity
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SearchQuery).InvokeCommand(this, x => x.Search);
    }

    // create a new result list and return it, async code removed for demo-simplicity
    private static async Task<List<SearchResult>> GenerateSearchResultAsync(string value)
    {
        var rv = new List<SearchResult>();
        rv.Add(new SearchResult(value + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.FFFF")));            
        return rv;
    }

}

public class SearchResult
{
    private string address;
    public SearchResult(string s)
    {
        this.Address = s;
    }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug when WeakReferences are mistakenly collected during GC.
I'm not knowledgable enough to do the debugging, but some other smart guys did:

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/806

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31415 (open xamarin bug report)

**Workaround:**

Add this class to your project:

```
public class ReactiveObservableCollection<T> : ReactiveList<T> 
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> ObservableCollection { private set; get; }

    public ReactiveObservableCollection()
    {
        this.ObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        ItemsAdded.Subscribe(ObservableCollection.Add);
        ItemsRemoved.Subscribe((x) => ObservableCollection.Remove(x));
    }
}
```

and use it instead of the ReactiveList:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject {

public ReactiveObservableCollection<SearchResult> SearchResults { set; get; }

public ViewModel() 
{
     // use ReactiveObservableCollection instead of ReactiveList
     this.SearchResults = new ReactiveObservableCollection<SearchResult>()
     {
        ChangeTrackingEnabled = true
     };
}
```

**Also, make sure to use the .ObservableCollection property on the collection as ItemSource (instead of just the collection)!**

```
this.ResultView.ItemsSource = viewModel.SearchResults.ObservableCollection;
```

instead of

<s>this.ResultView.ItemsSource = viewModel.SearchResults;</s>

This should solve the problem.

HTH!